# Cookie Expiration OWIN

Tags: asp.net-mvc, cookies, owin

I've recently noticed that the following cookies are being issued with a 1 year expiration:

__RequestVerificationToken
.AspNet.Cookies
.openidconnect.nonce.[guid]

If I add the following code, the .AspNet.Cookies will have the desired 15 minute expiration:

```
CookieAuthenticationOptions cookieAuthenticationOptions = new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
{
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        OnResponseSignIn = (CookieResponseSignInContext context) =>
        {
            context.CookieOptions.Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15);
        }
    }
};

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
app.UseCookieAuthentication(cookieAuthenticationOptions);
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions);
app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(windowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions);
```

However I can't figure out how to set a similar expiration time for the other cookies?